# Fixing security vulnerabilities in Cloud Function container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The containers that result from the standard Cloud Function build/deploy process sometimes contain security vulnerabilities, and I'm not sure how to resolve these since Cloud Functions don't (as far as I know) offer much control of the execution environment by design. What's the best practice for resolving security vulnerabilities in Google Cloud Functions?

If I can figure out how to extend the build process I think I'll be in good shape, but am not sure how to do that for Cloud Functions in particular.

Situation:

- I'm building my functions using the standard `gcloud functions deploy` command ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy)). The deployment is successful and I can successfully run the function - it creates a container in the Container Registry ([process overview](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying) -- sounds like its built off of the base Ubuntu Docker image).
- I'm using Google's container vulnerability scanning, and it detects security issues in these containers, presumably because some of the packages in the Ubuntu base image have released security updates. In other container environments, its straightforward enough to update these packages via `apt` or similar, but I'm not aware of how to perform the equivalent in a Cloud Function environment since you don't really customize the environment (Dockerfile, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.  Cloud Functions seeks to be as easy to use as possible by being opinionated about how to build the container.  You just provide the code.

If you want control over a serverless container, you should switch to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run), which lets you deploy the full container.  It also gives you a greater degree of control over the amount of concurrent requests it can handle, potentially saving you money by utilizing the virtual machine more fully.

Comment: Thanks @Doug - that makes sense.